# how to send mail with mailTo on submit

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I'm having two problems with this snipet:

```
1) for some reason the body is not updating with the innerHTML of #test

2) The client's email is coming up on the SHARE link but I can't get it to open on submit
```

```js
function Mailto_url(){
 var encode_mailto_component = function(str){
  try{ return encodeURIComponent(str); }
  catch(e){ return escape(str); }
 }
 var AddressList = function(){
  var list = [];
  this.length = 0;
  this.add = function(address){
   if(address) {
    list.push(address);
    this.length = list.length;
   }
  };
  this.get = function(){
   return list.join(';');
  };
 };
 var subject = '',
  body = '',
  mainList = new AddressList(),
  ccList = new AddressList(),
  bccList = new AddressList();
 this.setSubject = function(str){ subject = encode_mailto_component(str); }
 this.setBody = function(str){ body = encode_mailto_component(str); }
 this.addMain = function(x) { mainList.add(x); }
 this.addCC = function(x) { ccList.add(x); }
 this.addBCC = function(x) { bccList.add(x); }
 this.getURL = function(allow_empty_mainList){
  var out = ['mailto:'];
  var extras = [];
  if(mainList.length === 0 && !allow_empty_mainList){
   throw('Mailto_url: no main addressees');
  }
  else{
   out.push(mainList.get());
  }
  if(subject) { extras.push('subject=' + subject); }
  if(ccList.length) { extras.push('cc=' + ccList.get()); }
  if(bccList.length) { extras.push('bcc=' + bccList.get()); }
  if(body) { extras.push('body=' + body); }
  if(extras.length) { out.push('?' + extras.join('&')); }
  return out.join('');
 }
}

function getContent() {
 var mailTo = new Mailto_url();
  var test = document.getElementById('test');
mailTo.addMain('rssxyze@gmail.com');
mailTo.addMain('mrsairshow@ddd.net');
mailTo.addCC('linda@xyz.com');
mailTo.addCC('mandy@abc.com');
mailTo.addBCC('susanne@mno.com');
mailTo.addBCC('chris@mno.com');
mailTo.setSubject("test");
mailTo.setBody(test.innerHTML);
window.location=mailTo.getURL(true);
  
 
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">


    <form>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a class="home" href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="share" class="share" href="#" onclick="getContent()">Share Quote</a></li>
        <li>
          <a class="info" href="#"></a>
        </li>
        <li><input id='test' type='text'></input>
        </li>
        <li><input type='submit' onclick="getContent()"></input>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 2

```
<form onsubmit="return false">
```

change this lines

Comment: It also works without the line Mailto_url(); in the sendMail function.  Can you explain why when I call a function that calls a function it works but when called directly it doesn't?  Also, anyway to get the required popup from displaying if no text is added?

Comment: Thanks but I think I have.  on submit returns true and tries to submit form preventing the js from executing.  Placed a test inside of js and by passed the new window location and the required stays lit

Comment: actually you just need <form onsubmit="return false">

Answer (score 2):

```
mailTo.setBody(test.value);
```

It should not be innerHTML it should be value.
Also, there are no function calls in the code you posted.

Comment: Please explain the question a little more. When I added a function call the email dialog showed up.

Comment: the function call on the submit button doesn't seem to work.  Where or how did you add function call?